# Laravel maintenance mode refresh and render parameter

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, laravel-9

I am trying to put my application into maintenance mode via `php artisan down`.

`php artisan down --refresh=5` works fine and my browser refreshes after 5 seconds

If I want to render a custom maintenance view with `php artisan down --render="maintenance.index"` it renders the view located in `resources/views/maintenance/index.blade.php` like I want it to do.

But when I am using both parameters like this

```sh
php artisan down --render="maintenance.index" --refresh=5
```

It just renders the custom view but is not refreshing after 5 seconds. I thought maybe it matters in which order I type in the parameters. But it doesn't work either way.

```sh
php artisan down --refresh=5 --render="maintenance.index"
```

Is there a possibility to put my app into maintenance mode, rendering a custom view and refreshing the page every 5 seconds without editing the default `503.blade.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the 5 seconds at anytime for your custom maintenance view, simply add the `refresh` html tag

```html
<head>
    <title>{{ config('app.name') }}</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>
```

On top of my head, I'm not sure what the `refresh` attribute changes in laravel to apply this dynamically in your template, but I'll investigate this further a little bit later today.

### Edit 1:

Laravel stores stub file for the maintenance mode but I could not find a result which affects the `refresh` argument in combination with `render`.

However I found a workaround to archive the same. The `refresh` attribute is in the `$_SERVER['argv']` environment variable, which can easily parsed and added to your blade view:

```
@php
    $result = array_values(preg_grep('/(--refresh)/', array_values( $_SERVER['argv'] ) ));
    if(!empty($result)){
      $refresh = substr($result[0], strpos($result[0], "=") + 1);
    }
@endphp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{{ config('app.name') }}</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    @if(isset($refresh))
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="{{$refresh}}">
    @endif
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

<!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- your content here... -->


</body>
</html>
```

### Edit 2:

This [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/42208) is now fixed in Laravel [PR [8.x] Fix refresh during down #42217](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/42217)

Comment: Thanks for your solution I thought the mistake was mine but apparently not. Thanks for reporting the bug on github.